# Microsoft SQL - Update while Select

Tags: sql-server

is there any way to update while selecting data to avoid extra accesses?

We select 2500 datasets and need to set a value to 1 while we do this, current solution WOULD be to do it in the profile, 1 by 1, which leads to 2500 accesses to the database...

Comment: Using a stored procedure would solve this, allowing you to perform whatever logic you require before returning one or more resultsets. Btw, your title states _Microsoft SQL_ but you've tagged the question _mysql_.

Comment: Microsoft SQL = SQL server ?

Comment: I am actually just confused as to how to call it - we use SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, is that Microsoft SQL?

Comment: That's Microsoft SQL Server, yes. It's not, however, MySQL which is what you have tagged.

Comment: A select is a non-update query so no.

Comment: No, you can't. but you can update multiple rows at the same time - just use an update statement with the same where clause as your select statement.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah, that was the idea I had, there is no really good solution sadly...but I guess we will run by that

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your `SELECT` query into an `UPDATE` easily.

I don't know what your `SELECT` looks like, but you could follow this pattern:

```
SELECT
    c.column1
    , b.column2
    , a.column3
FROM Table1 a
    INNER JOIN Table2 b
        ON a.PK = b.FK
    INNER JOIN Table3 c
        ON b.PK = c.FK
WHERE a.column4 = 'a'
    AND b.column4 = 'x'
```

to

```
UPDATE a
SET column3 = 1
    , column4 = 'b'
FROM Table1 a
    INNER JOIN Table2 b
        ON a.PK = b.FK
    INNER JOIN Table3 c
        ON b.PK = c.FK
WHERE a.column4 = 'a'
    AND b.column4 = 'x'
```

This will do 1 database access and do all the work.

Comment: But that won't give me the results of the select, right?
We select data in the beginning to be processed by a follow up profile. The idea is to set an "ErrorField" to 1 in case the profile runs into a value-problem. Currently it will again and again run over the wrong data until someone fixes the data, which can happen all over the weekend and nothing is being processed.

Comment: @Dex Yes, it won't. But it will solve your UPDATE problem. However, if you're still doing 2500 database accesses for your SELECTs, then your problem is elsewhere and much bigger. You'd need to do some big refactoring.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by that :/ The mistake is on my end as I haven't clarified what I really want or rather why, I just wanted to know if it's possible or not.
We select and would need to update seperately selected lines, but it would need to be done 1 by 1 as a batch is not possible (because they are afterwards split). So I wanted to avoid 5000 Updates on 2500 data sets every 7 minutes :)

Comment: Ok, so if your current design is hard to switch from doing selects on 2500 data sets then the only way to update the data and also return it is to `UPDATE` then `SELECT`. There's no way around this.